# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE stops imports at 69k rows

Tags: mysql, import, command-line-interface

I am using the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE and it seems to be stopping at ~69k rows.

Is is a memory limit that's too low? of buffer size?

```
Query OK, 68844 rows affected, 65535 warnings (4.20 sec)
Records: 69182  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 338  Warnings: 160539
```

The .csv file contains around 138k entries, all escaped and enclosed properly.

Edit: Mysql version: `Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.50, for Win32 (ia32)`

Edit 2: The command:

```
load data local infile 'path/to/file.csv' into table contacts
fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'
(column1, column2, column3,...)
```

Comment: all the time is the same row ?

Comment: if it's ok, so why do You have `Skipped: 338  Warnings: 160539` ?

Comment: ...about 138000 entries but 160539 warnings ?!? You probably have to examine these using [`SHOW WARNINGS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-warnings.html): I *guess* your missing rows are there...

Comment: @jaczes I haven't specifically skipped anything. I edited my question with the cli command

Comment: Ugh, Looks like it was a line endings issue. I changed to using `\r\n` for line endings and it worked. I also changed my MYSQL MODE to be `MYSQL40` - apparently that removes the 'skip import row on default value not found'. @SylvainLeroux Tx for the show warnings, it helped :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my last comment, Make sure the line endings you select corresponds with your OS that you used to make the .csv file.

> Ugh, Looks like it was a line endings issue. I changed to using \r\n for line endings and it worked. I also changed my MYSQL MODE to be MYSQL40 - apparently that removes the 'skip import row on default value not found'. @SylvainLeroux Tx for the show warnings, it helped :D

I was looking for Unix based line endings that resulted in the mysql import reading it as one line.