# How can I insert more than 100,000 rows into a MySQL DB using LOAD INFILE?

Tags: mysql, database, csv

I have several csv files that I need to put into a MySQL DB. All of them have more than 100,000 rows. THe smallest is 600,000+.

How can I circumvent the 100,000 limit?

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with trying insert 600.00 rows with load infile?

Comment: More than 600,000 rows. The Load Infile command will load 100,000 rows and then end.  I could split the files, but I need to do this for a lot of files, and would rather understand why this is happening.

Comment: I think there is some local problem with your setup. Officialy there are no limits mentioned about load infile, other than hardware memory limits

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any limits that MySQL imposes with the load infile.  Have you looked at this Q&A: [LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE stops imports at 69k rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995827/load-data-local-infile-stops-imports-at-69k-rows)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I resolved it by using the following `mysqlimport` command:

```
mysqlimport -u root -ppa --local checkpostcode npzip.csv --fields-terminated-by=, --fields-enclosed-by="
```